# A cube on rotating cylinder not moving

Tags: unity

i have an cylinder with self-rotating script,

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class rotate : MonoBehaviour {

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (0, 0, 30) * (float)5);
    }
}
```

[image]
i placed a cube  (not at center) with rigidbody on the cylinder, but it is not moving, anyone know how to make it moves according to the cylinder except using make parent?

Answer (score 1):

i assume you did these :

1) added rigidbody to both objects.

2) unchecked gravity for cylinder and freeze its vertical position(y is the default) and freeze rotation except vertical.

---

i would use a fixed joint or spring joint and connect both body together.
just place the cube where you want it to be then add fixed joint.

spring joint makes it more dynamic for example if you want the cube to stay in a specific radius but moves with different speed .

---

can use "Break force" option to make joint to break after it reaches desired speed.
also you can use "rigidbody.addtorque()" instead of transform rotate to let physics handle the rotation.

Comment: i want the box will drop on the cylinder, than the box will stay on the cylinder and rotating, but after i added a fixed joint, the box will not drop and rotate with the cylinder immediately.

Comment: after added a fixed joint.
http://s15.postimg.org/vvdmlgl49/unity3d_p5.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use `Rigidbody.addTorque()` if the rotation speed is too low (I think there was some "motor" join, but I'm not sure now). That way the physics engine will move the cube because of the velocity of the cylinder. (*Make sure that the cube and the cylinder have some friction (e.g. >0.5), otherwise **nothing** will happen!*)

The problem with the joint method is that it doesn't allow for the cube to fall from above, or fall off (break speed might do it, but only to some extend).

Comment: where should i add the actual code?